# PyQt5 problems with CMD

Tags: python-3.x, pip

i need some help . I tried to install PyQt5 with CMD  in window but when i enter pip install pyqt5-tools , i got this error : [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wGkqy.png)

how can I fix it????

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem here.
I found out that PyQt5 is not supported on the 3.10 version of Python, only the 3.9. You can check this info [here](https://pypi.org/project/pyqt5-tools/).

So I downgraded my Python version and everything worked fine.